# Ansible playbook task - Command cannot find pid, but the service was started correctly

Tags: ansible

I have configured a playbook to install, configure, and start the osquery tool. The playbook executes with an error. *"osqueryd is not running. no pidfile found."*

Full error

```
TASK [osquery-client : check agent status again] ********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [13.57.34.71]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/osqueryctl", "status"], "delta": "0:00:00.021902", "end": "2019-10-16 19:19:50.523876", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 7, "start": "2019-10-16 19:19:50.501974", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "osqueryd is not running. no pidfile found.", "stdout_lines": ["osqueryd is not running. no pidfile found."]}
```

My task/main.yml is defined as:

```
- name: check agent status again
  command: /usr/bin/osqueryctl status
  ignore_errors: yes
```

And the pid file is located here

```
--pidfile=/var/run/osqueryd.pidfile
```

Is ansible looking in the wrong place for the pid?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this sleep command into the task seemed to work

```
- name: check agent status again
  command: /usr/bin/osqueryctl status
  command: sleep 5
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible does not look for the pid file. It executes /usr/bin/osqueryctl status. What does it return if you execute it by hand?

Comment: ```# /usr/bin/osqueryctl status
osqueryd is already running: 4354```